# Spring data neo4j embedded remote shell connection not allowed

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I am trying to connect embedded server but always getting

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to lock org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel@5ceccc52
```

This is my configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

public static final Setting<Boolean> remote_shell_enabled = Settings.setting("remote_shell_enabled", Settings.BOOLEAN, Settings.TRUE);
public static final Setting<Boolean> enable_remote_shell = Settings.setting("enable_remote_shell", Settings.BOOLEAN, Settings.TRUE);
public Neo4jConfig() {
    setBasePackage("com.repo", "com.model");
}

@Bean
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("neo.db2")
            .setConfig(enable_remote_shell, "true")
            .newGraphDatabase();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to connect the shell?

Just do:

`bin/neo4j-shell`

*No* `-path` parameter !! As then you would start a new database on the same directory.

Comment: When i just type to neo4j-shell get this exception.   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused